# Stripe custom connect account parameter error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

Stripe says invalid array. error occurs when creating Custom connect account with this parameter.

```
documents : {passport : {files : "file name"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passport isn't a valid field within "documents." See [this API spec](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create#create_account-documents) to look at the valid options to pass within "documents."